# counting integers and strings differently on pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas, count, integer

i am a beginner on pandas. I had two columns and i combined them.

I tried to count every row by each state and each id number.  I have thousands of id and state so, can somebody help me about my problem??  Thank you.

```
draft= df[["ID", "STATE" ]]

draft
Out[5]: 
           ID                                         STATE
0          11                                 chr1:100154376:G:A
1           2                                 chr1:100177723:C:T
2           9                                 chr1:100177723:C:T
3           1                                chr1:100194200:-:AA
4           8                                  chr1:10032249:A:G
5           2                                 chr1:100340787:G:A
6           1                                 chr1:100349757:A:G
7           3                                  chr1:10041186:C:A
8          10                                 chr1:100476986:G:C
9           4                                 chr1:100572459:C:T
10          5                                 chr1:100572459:C:T


chars = "TGC-"
number = {}

for item in chars:
    d = draft
    At = d.str.contains("A:" + item)
    num = At.value_counts(sort=True)
    number[item] = num
    id_num1=sd["ID"].value_counts()
    id_values1= id_num1.order()
```

Comment: You want `At = d['STATE'].str.contains("A:" + char3)` `str` attribute is available for 'Series` not `DataFrame` so you want to call it on a column

Comment: Also what is `number[char3] = num`?, also what do you expect `id_1 = d.sort("draft")["draft"]` to do? 'draft' isn't a column in `d`

Comment: @EdChum thank you for your first comment. Ok, i deleted id_1 part.(I really don't know why i wrote). I try to analyse this column by row by row and want to get both id and state.  ATnum = number["T"] gives me the number of state but how can i connect it with id and count them?

Answer (score 1):

This is my first ever answer on stackoverflow. Please ignore it, if it doesn't make sense. I'm not a veteran coder -- but I love pandas. I think you want to do something like this.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
ids = [21,2,9,1,8,2,1,3,10,4,4]
states = ['GA','CT','AA','AG','CA','GC','CT','CT','CA','AG','AG']
draft = pd.DataFrame({'ids':ids,'state':states})
draft

d = dict()
for dex, row in draft.iterrows():
    x = row['ids']
    y = row['state']

    if y in d:
        # append the new state to the existing array at this slot
        d[y].append(x)
    else:
        # create a new array in this slot
        d[y] = [x]
```

The new dictionary with states and counts:

```
d
{'AA': [9],
 'AG': [1, 4, 4],
 'CA': [8, 10],
 'CT': [2, 1, 3],
 'GA': [21],
 'GC': [2]}
```

Showing the result:

```
for key, value in d.iteritems():
     print key, len(value)

AA 1
AG 3
CA 2
GC 1
GA 1
CT 3
```